# Backbone, keep the same menu between views

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am using Backbone, and I have a menu which remains the same, on several views.

It sounds simple at first but I find this **hard to implement** because, **once a view is changed, I empty every elemnt inside it**.

This leave me with two choices:

1. add the menu each time a view is loaded;
2. keep the menu globally, on the dom level and instruct backbone not to delete certain elements on view change == **this is really a bad ideea, messing up everything big time**.

Performance wise, lets say I have the follwoing situation:

```
// View 1

$('.nav').html(<div class="mydiv">this is my div</div>);
```

and on:

```
// View 2 

$('.nav').html(<div class="mydiv">this is my div</div>);
```

What will the browser do, and what will jquery do?

If jquery sees I'm trying to add the same html as before, will ignore the command?

Any ideas?

How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate view for the navigation.

```
<div id="nav-region"></div>
<div id="content-region"></div>
```

Instantiate and show view separatly

```
var navigation = new Backbone.view.extend({});
var viewOne = new Backbone.view.extend({});

$("#nav-region").append(navigation.render().el);
$("#content-region").append(viewOne.render().el);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the menu statically in your index page and inject your changing views into a separate element with backbone:

```
<body>
    <!-- backbone doesn't need to alter this -->
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/view-1">Menu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/view-2">Menu item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/view-3">Menu item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- inject your views into this element when the route changes -->
    <div class="view"></div>
</body>
```